# Firebase phone auth without code verification nor recaptcha

Tags: javascript, wordpress, firebase, web, firebase-authentication

I am new in firebase and I am trying to integrate my WordPress authentication with firebase auth. my aim is: "when User registers on wordpress, to create a user on firebase with phoneNumber authentication for mobile app", is there a way to do firebase phone number auth through web, without Recaptcha verifier nor SMS code verification.

I created firebase account with email and password, and tried to update the User phoneNumber but without success (tried updateProfile and updatePhoneNumber)

I welcome any other idea or method for this integration (firebase/wordpress user creation)

Thank you

Comment: You seem to want to just set the phone number without verification as a user attribute (like address, gender, etc). You may as well save the phone number in your database for that user.

Comment: Thank you Bojeil, currently user register and authenticate by email and password through web and I am saving the phone number and address in the database. I am looking for a way to make user can sign in on his mobile application with his phone number that he inserted on web. is there a way to make the authentication provider phone instead of email and password, by passing the phone number through web without verifications.